# JavaScript: How to search for a string that includes regular expression symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, string, search

I am basically just starting with JavaScript, and this is my first post to stack overflow. I have no doubt the answer is somewhere here or that I am making some trespass, but I have a near nonexistent understanding of regular expressions.

My problem is that I am trying to search a string for the string
"[PROCESSED]"
basically written like so:
    if(stringToSearch.search("[PROCESSED]")==-1)

Results "true" if the string is not found. The issue is that it is interpreted as a regular expression, and searches for each digit between the brackets. Instead, I want it to interpret the string as is, without interpreting the brackets as parameters for the search. Is there a symbol I put in front of [PROCESSED] that ensures the brackets are NOT parameters but instead just treated as text like the PROCESSED that is inside?

I'll take any criticism about the code or stack overflow etiquette, I just want an answer to this because it's been really problematic.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: I switched to indexOf and it yields the desired result! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexOf satisfies the need to search without using the brackets as parameters! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the brackets around PROCESSED? If yes, try to escape the brackets with
 `("\[PROCESSED\]")`

Answer (score -1):

Your first question, my first answer:  I'm not a javascript programmer, but have you tried using a backslash ("\") before the bracket symbols?

Comment: Downvote with no comment is lame.  OP asked for a symbol to prevent regex interpretation.  Did I forget to phrase my response in the form of a question, Alex?